# C# MVC form doesn't work with input form attribute

Tags: asp.net-mvc, forms, validation, razor, attributes

I need to use form inside table cell with fields in another cells. I'm using input  [form attribute](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_form.asp). MVC passing data to controller works correctly but validation before form send doesn't work with this attribute.

```
<tr>
<td>
    @Html.EditorFor(model => item.Code, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control inline-edit", form = "editForm" + item.Id } })
    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => item.Code)
</td>
<td>
    @Html.EditorFor(model => item.Name, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control inline-edit", form = "editForm" + item.Id } })
    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => item.Name)
</td>
<td class="text-right">
    @using (Html.BeginForm("UpdatePrintMaterial", "Production", FormMethod.Post, new { id = "editForm" + item.Id }))
    {
        @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
        @Html.HiddenFor(model => item.Id)
        <button class="btn btn-default save" data-toggle="tooltip" title="Zapisz"><i class="fa fa-save"></i></button>
    }
</td></tr>
```

How to workaroud this issue to use validation before sending data?

Comment: Short answer is no. MVC's client side validation (using `jquery.validate.unobtrusive.js`and `jquery.validate.js` only works for form controls inside a `<form>` element. It would be better to use layout elements (positioning, floats etc) to mimic a table, rather than a `<table>` element.

Comment: However, having multiple forms (one for each row) makes no sense - you can only submit one form at a time. If you want to be able to make edits on multiple rows, then have a single form and generate the view correctly using a `for` loop or `EditorTemplate` - currently your code wont even work correctly because your name attributes do not match your model) - refer [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30094047/html-table-to-ado-net-datatable/30094943#30094943).

Comment: Alternatively, have an edit link in each row and display a dialog form for editing a row.